# Extraxt & save all text() with Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I'd like to extract the text from an HTML file using Python. I want essentially the same output I would get if I copied the text from a browser and pasted it into notepad. To solve this problem I need to use the framework. As an example, take a page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page, thus extract 100 pages without leaving the domain en.wikipedia.org

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple basic code sample doing what you need.

```
from scrapy import Spider


class Foo(Spider):
    # start urls executed at the beginning
    # with default callback "parse"
    start_urls = ["https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page"]
    name = "basic_spider"

    def parse(self, response):
        # use css or xpath selectors to extract text
        print(response.css("::text").extract())
```

Save above as spider.py and run it with

```
scrapy runspider spider.py
```

Start with [Scrapy tutorial](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html) if you feel something is not clear or needs improving feel free to improve the docs, they are hosted on github.

Of course you must learn [Python first](https://docs.python.org/2/), so start with learning Python if you dont know it already.

Comment: That it extracts only the main page? How to extract 100 random pages are in this domain? How correctly use allowed_domains

Comment: More appeared in the text function names and symbols of the transfer, for example,\u, \t... I heard that to extract text better use xpath, you can please his example?

Comment: this is all in documentation, [allowed_domains](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html?highlight=allowed%20domains#scrapy.spiders.Spider.allowed_domains) is just spider attribute e.g. `allowed_domains = ["en.wikipedia.org"]` extracting links is just finding html `<a>` elements to yield requests for all links just do `for link response.xpath("//a/@href"): yield scrapy.Request(link, callback=self.your_spider_method)` see [here](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html#following-links)

Comment: I do: 'for link in response.xpath("//a/@href): yield scrapy.Request(link, callback = self.parse)' , and gives an error  "Request url must be str or unicode".  And the example of the css I kept the text in the notes like this: 'f1.write(str(response.css("::text").extract()))', and in this case?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19665/the-help-vampire-problem